# How to create a screen sharing extension in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, webrtc, mozilla

I am actually creating an extension that capture your screen video. I have found some examples that create screen sharing extension in firefox using WebRTC. But, its really hard to implement it. Does anyone have any project that share screen.

Thanks,

Comment: Very cool idea, Im not sure how to do it myself but it would be awesome. WebRTC is super cool I didnt know we can do this with it.

Comment: Hi Noitidart. Here are some links that help in capturing screen. I am unable to use these in my own ways. i.e by creating my own extension. Please let me know if you can figure out how to create an extension of screen.
https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RTCMultiConnection/screen-sharing.html

Comment: I chatted around a bit, people are recommending you use something other then WebRTC. Because WebRTC may not be as powerful and addons offer so much more power. Apparently WebRTC screensharing websites exist out there. But if you want to, definitely do it, it would be nice to have on market place. Here is an example: https://github.com/opentok/screensharing-extensions/tree/master/firefox/ScreenSharing

Comment: Thank you Sir. I will try implementing it. Will get back to you once I am successful in it. Also, I will email you the results.

Comment: Looking forward to an awesome addon from you! :) Thanks for your work! :) It would be best to share here in open, link to github etc so other people benefit too :)

Comment: @Noitidart not sure who says WebRTC is not powerful. It powers screensharing in [Firefox Hello](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/share-your-screen-firefox-hello), and it works great! An extension would have access to the same functionality, and be able to white-list sites in about:webrtc. Or try this simple demo page (requires some about:config): https://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/gum_test.html

Comment: I agree with @jib. WebRTC is a powerful tool and it gives much more sreensharing workaround in an easier way.

Comment: Hey @Yash how are you capturing the screen? Or are you capturing only the firefox window?

Comment: Hi Noitidart. I am successful in creating a screen sharing extension for firefox. I did it via bootstrap.js. defining the webserver for which I have to make the screen sharing work.It worked. I will create a new question here at StackOverflow for those people who are struggling with this as I struggled as well

Comment: Hi @Yash I was curious to see how you did this. May you please share github repo to your firefox extension

Answer (score 3):

Just an update: Firefox from version 52 doesn't require an extension for the screen sharing.

> The Screensharing whitelist is no longer needed to share your screen
>   or windows starting Firefox 52 (April). Please let us know if you find
>   any problems!

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Screensharing

Comment: does firefox still have this feature? cant seem to find it anywhere

Comment: which feature sorry? Firefox doesn't need any whitelist or extension

Comment: the screen sharing feature, how do you use it, cant find any information on it.

Comment: @arana https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [getScreenMedia](https://github.com/otalk/getScreenMedia) there is a [Firefox Extension Sample](https://github.com/otalk/getScreenMedia/tree/master/firefox-extension-sample). There is also source code from [webrtc-experiment](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing/).

Just a quick gotcha: As far as I know you have to whitelist your domain in `about://config`, or request be on the whitelist (like talky.io).